# Simple Shortcode (Wordpress) does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my "code":

```
   function whoop_function(){

        return "whoop whoop!";
    }

add_shortcode('whoop', 'whoop_function' );
```

Now when I want to use it in a post, all I get is:

> [whoop]

As you can see I am very new and unused to it so maybe the answer is really simple, maybe I've just miss a thing in advance.
I both checked defining the function in functions.php and also in content.php

Comment: Where did you add this code. in function.php or plugin ???

Comment: i test your shortcode will work for me. how you call your shortcode ? inside page or in template using do_shortcode ?

Comment: Its working for me too, he would have put it at wrong place

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

For shortcode function echo is required.

Please check with below code

```
function whoop_function(){

 $responseData = "whoop whoop!";
 echo $responseData;
 return true;
}
add_shortcode('whoop', 'whoop_function' );
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's just working with do_shortcode('[whoop]') and not in the backend post or page section.

Comment: If you are looking for widget section than use this code. add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

Answer (score 0):

put your code in `themes/function.php` files and remove from content.php as function is duplicated so function already defined PHP error occurred.

```
function whoop_function(){

        return "whoop whoop!";
    }

add_shortcode('whoop', 'whoop_function' );
```

and add your shortcode `[whoop]` in any page content section.

if u use `do_shortcode('[whoop]');` then echo it like below.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[whoop]'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the code either in one of the files. do_shortcode works for me but if i want to use [whoop] in a page or post it still does not work.

Comment: your code is work for me in both case inside page content and using do_shortcode

Comment: if u user shortcode in page what will show in page when u run page. share output.

Comment: Thats my output:

Get the post field where used "[whoop]": [whoop]
do_shortcode in content.php: whoop whoop!

Comment: So when used in a post it's just the blank text.

Comment: inside shortcode function try to echo some content insted return and check, may be you are not used any visual editor so.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. I think you are using it in a template. Just need to use it as mentioned below :

In files:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[whoop]'); ?>
```

In admin pages or posts:

```
[whoop]
```

Fetch the content like this:

```
        $post_content = get_post(get_id_by_slug('short')); // assuming that you have already defined get_id_by_slug function as you are using it in your code and "short" is a slug for post you are fetching content
        $content = $post_content->post_content;
        echo do_shortcode( $content );
```

You are fetching content without considering the short code. Update your code as above. 
Hope it will work for you.

Comment: In files it works fine but unfortunately not in admin pages or posts.

Comment: check you content.php file, I think you have done some operations related to the content. something with the brackets, because it is working completely fine to me.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by that.
Can you please be a little more specific?

I get my post where i try out the shortcodes like that:
<?php echo get_post_field( 'post_content', get_id_by_slug( 'short' ) ); ?>
get_id_ny_slug is a function that speaks for it self and works properly.

Comment: Updated my answer according to your problem, try it now. I am sure it will solve it.